# building WordPress plugin with bootstrap without interfering existing theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress

I have a very specific question, related to the context: I'm re-building a WP plugin that have already 1000+ active install.

I was thinking using Twitter bootstrap to make good responsiveness of my views, and adding it like this :

```
add_action('wp_head','head_code');
function head_code(){
    // compiled and minified CSS
    $headcode = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">';
    echo $headcode;
}
```

The problem this is totally interfering with the installed theme (changing the layout). I can't change anything in the theme nor the WP install, this is just a plugin that can be downloaded for the WP repository and have some backend and frontend views, I shouldn't change anything that is already existing on the website.

So I see only 2 ways :
1. I can "isolate" the bootstrap css only for my view's usage. If possible, how?
2. I have to use a more standard was of developing WP plugin and use other responsiveness best practice. What's your oppinion / feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap classes create conflicts with your actual theme, I found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/onigetoc/20c4c3933cabd8672e3e) of bootstrap 3 with a wrapper called `.bootstrap-wrapper` for avoiding conflicts.

You can also use this [css prefix tool](http://www.css-prefix.com) with the last version of bootstrap.

Comment: You're welcome :) @Iteration ! Please accept my answer as a correct answer :)

Comment: It's what I was trying to do but I got a message "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: I will come back when I will have all this "reputation" and give you the point!